# a tag inheritance screwing things up css

Tags: html, css

Currently I've got somewhere in my css a:visited{color:purple} thing is this works fine for hyperlinks but I created a button using some css and an a tag but the problem is that I don't want it to inherit the visited color, how do I change this ?

Answer (score 2):

So use a stronger selector like

```
.button a:visited {
   color: #000;
}
```

And over ride the default one.

Comment: .myButton a:visited {
   color: #FFFFF;
}

Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @user2201065 You are having only 5 f's, it's hex, has to be 6

Answer (score 1):

The `:visited` psuedoclass has the same specificity as a class, so if your button is just `.button` it will win. However, if you use `a.button` then it will lose if the button is defined after the `:visited` style. You can further boost the specificity with something like `html a.button` to guarantee a win.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still fairly new at CSS and I don't quite get where your coming from.

.myButton a:visited {
   color: #FFFFF;
}

This is what I have that's not working.